# Select last element of item in a list with the DOM

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Without using jQuery (because I have yet to even start that section yet), and just using some good old JavaScript/DOM, how could I select the last element of an item in a list.

For example I have the following HTML:

```html
<section id="container">
  <ul>
    <li class="first">one</li>
    <li class="second">two</li>
    <li class="third">three</li>
  </ul>
  <ol>
    <li class="first">one</li>
    <li class="second">two</li>
    <li class="third">three</li>
  </ol>
</section>
```

And I want to select this item and return it in the DOM:  `<li class="third">three</li>` from the `ol` list.
I understand that `document.querySelector` only selects the first element in the document, which would be `document.querySelector('li.third')`. How would I do the opposite and select the last?

Comment: Which list, `ol` or `ul`?

Comment: 'ol' is what I am aiming for @Mr.Polywhirl

Comment: `#container ol li.third`?

Comment: li.third from the ol list @Justinas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get your item, you need to select properly.
This means you need to be specific when you want to select `.third`

Sequence to select `#container` -> `ol` -> (either `li:last-child` or `li.third`)

```
document.querySelector("#container > ol > li.third");
```

Comment: This makes sense, I was unaware you could structure `querySelector` that way, thank you!

Comment: You don't actually need the part at the end to be a compound type/class selector (`li.third`). The direct descendant of an ordered list `ol` is always going to be a list item `li`. You should always strive to make your selectors as simple and with as low a specificity as possible. You can just write: `document.querySelector("#container > ol > .third");`

Answer (score 4):

You can use `*:last-child` if you have mixed child elements.

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('#container *:last-child .third').textContent);
```

```html
<section id="container">
  <ul>
    <li class="first">one</li>
    <li class="second">two</li>
    <li class="third">three</li>
  </ul>
  <ol>
    <li class="first">one</li>
    <li class="second">two</li>
    <li class="third">three (here)</li>
  </ol>
</section>
```

You can also grab the the last child by either:

- `#container *:last-child li:last-of-type` or
- `#container *:last-child li:last-child`

Answer (score 0):

You can use 
document.querySelector('ol li:last-child')