# How to get last child from parent element using query selector method?

Tags: javascript, jquery-selectors

For example:

```
<div class="list-container">
  <p>hello<p>
  <p>hello<p>
  <p>hello<p>
  <p>hello<p>
</div>
```

How to get that last child element? I would like to point out that the children elements are dynamically created and keep increasing or decreasing according to the user's whim. And I want to be able to pick the last child every time this happens. That's why I ask. Plz, share me the syntax. Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select last element of item in a list with the DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59630017/select-last-element-of-item-in-a-list-with-the-dom)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.list-container > p:last-child` will do

And please, avoid bloatware, such as jquery...

```js
console.log(document.querySelector(".list-container > p:last-child"));
```

```html
<div class="list-container">
  <p>hello1</p>
  <p>hello2</p>
  <p>hello3</p>
  <p>hello4</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a reference to the parent, you can also get the last child with DOM APIs with [`Node.lastChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/lastChild).

Or use [`Element.lastElementChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/lastElementChild) to exclude non-element nodes like text and comment nodes.

```js
var list = document.getElementById("list-container");
var last = list.lastElementChild
var text = last.textContent
console.log(text); // hello4
```

```html
<div id="list-container">
  <p>hello1</p>
  <p>hello2</p>
  <p>hello3</p>
  <p>hello4</p>
</div>
```